# Check which interval range does a number lie in between

Tags: algorithms

I have an array of time variables `t(1), t(2), ..., t(n).` and corresponding variables `v(1), v(2), ..., v(n).` Given a time `tx`, I would like to efficiently find between which interval `(t(i), t(i+1)]` does the number lie. Correspondingly, the variable `vx` needs to be interpolated which can be done easily afterwards.

P.S: The time `t(i=1)` is initialized with `t1` and is always increasing and greater than zero.

Comment: Do you know [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)?

Comment: @Tassle: Thanks, I am vaguely aware of it and will look into. After posting question, I realize that there is some predictability meaning that the search interval will keep shrinking if I store the index `i`, since time is always increasing.